# Why are my UI buttons in Unity not interacting with the mouse pointer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I was making a Tower Defense game, and I hade made an upgrade UI, all I had to do was change it from on hover over the tower to on click. I made it on-click, and it worked fine, until later. All the buttons just stopped working, but ***ONLY*** in the upgrades and sell UI. The hover effect doesn't even work anymore.

Here's what I have:

> - A Camera assigned to the Canvas seeing as it is world space.
> - An EventSystem.
> - Interactable and Raycast Target enabled on the buttons, but nothing else.
> - A Graphic Raycaster, a Canvas, Canvas Scaler, and a Canvas Group on the Canvas.

Here's what I have tried:

> - I have tested the EventSystem for registering the PointerEnter and PointerClick, no results. It's like the buttons don't exist.
> - Moving the buttons outside of the Panel.
> - Deleting the Empty GameObject that was a parent to the Canvas.
> - At least four questions on Stack Overflow.
> - At least two questions on Stack Exchange.
> - At least six questions on the official Unity site.
> - At least two videos.
> - ***AND I DID EVERY SINGLE TRICK IN EVERY SINGLE ONE OF THE ANSWERS.***

Here are some screenshots of things in the game:

[The Hierarchy in the Scene:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRBKu.png)

[The Hierarchy in a tower:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oTY8.png)

[What the tower looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0aIF.png)

[The EventSystem being unresponive with the buttons:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgiQF.png)

[Button config?:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWIq.png)

`Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject);`

Result:

`null null null null null null null null null null null null null null null null` even when I click on buttons that work.

Ask me if you need any other information, just ask. I'm getting extremely desperate.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I like that you added a lot of details, however when asking a question refrain from adding the introduction/story bit at the beginning, its irrelevant and nobody likes to read, else we would be reading books instead :)

Comment: Do you have a callback set on the button?

Comment: If you are manually adding interfaces for the button, have you tried making sure IPointerEnterHandler & IPointerExitHandler are implemented (not just one)? (Paste the relevant button code here please)

Comment: Yes... Also, what's an IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandler? @Aggressor

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your button configuration. What I had mentioned above are interfaces: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html

Comment: Also, can you put some code in an update loop. In any Update() method for an object in your scene can you print out `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` every frame then click your button and tell me what it prints out?

Comment: @Aggressor   Oh btw thought I should update... Remade the entire game and changed the code for the UI and it worked :P. Thanks for trying to help!